# Do I need a single loop or a nested loop for this?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting, for-loop

Let's say I have an array and a boolean method. This boolean method will return true if all the positive numbers appear before all the non-positive numbers (0 inclusive). Otherwise, it will return a false value.
The first array newArrayTrue will return a true value because all the positive numbers appear before all the non-positive numbers and 0. Whereas in newArrayFalse, it will return a false value because 0 appear before 5, and 5 is a positive number.

```
int[] newArrayTrue = {3,1,-4,0,-5};
int[] newArrayFalse = {3,1,-4,0,5};

public static boolean isPositiveFirst(int[] numbers) {

for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  for (int j=i+1; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > 0  && (numbers[i+1] < 0 || numbers[i+1] == 0)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
return false;
}
}
```

Do I need to have a nested for loop inside the boolean method or it can be done in just one for loop? And I need help with my conditions as I don't really get what's the issue with it. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
public static boolean isPositiveFirst(int[] numbers) {
    for(int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       if(numbers[i] > 0 && numbers[i-1] <= 0) {
           return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also some credit to @Ryan, since he deleted his answer on which I based my code.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to check whether the array is shorter or equal to one. In that case it won't enter the loop and return true anyhow...

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a boolean variable encounteredNegative and set it to true if you encounter a 0 or a negative number. Then continue the iteration and if a positive number is found the method should return false. If the loop ends the method returns true.

Something like this:

```
public static boolean isPositiveFirst(int[] numbers) {

    boolean encounteredNegative = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] <= 0) {
            encounteredNegative = true;
        } else {
            if (encounteredNegative) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Let's say I can only use one boolean method and not creating a new method. What do I have to do inside the current boolean method?

Comment: @宿命的な孤独 encounteredNegative is not a method it is a variable.

Comment: I am aware of it after looking it twice. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
    private static boolean areAllPositiveFirst(int[] a)
    {
        boolean f=false,ans=true;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if(f && a[i]>0)
            {
                ans=false;
                break;
            }
            if(a[i]<=0)
                f=true;
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the given answers, using IntStream you can do something like :

```
public static boolean isPositiveFirst(int[] numbers) {
    int k = IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).filter(i -> numbers[i]<1).findFirst().orElse(-1);
    if(k < 0) 
        return true;        
    else 
        return IntStream.of(Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, k, numbers.length)).filter(i-> i>0).count() <1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that Lyubomir Papazov already came up with this algorithm. My implementation is just a little more terse:

```
public static boolean isPositiveFirst(int[] numbers) {
    boolean seenNonPositive = false;
    for(int i : numbers) {
        if(i < 1) seenNonPositive = true;
        else if(seenNonPositive) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```